# Is it possible to simulate shortcut key events programmatically on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**Is it possible to simulate  shortcut key events programmatically on Chrome in JavaScript?**

I just want to trigger the shortcut event in javascript and show the chrome extension popup.html without clicking the icon. I tried many ways,but failed.

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script>
   function keypressEvt() {
       var keyboardEvent = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
       var initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? 'initKeyboardEvent' : 'initKeyEvent';
       keyboardEvent[initMethod](
                'keypress', // event type: keydown, keyup, keypress
                true, // bubbles
                true, // cancelable
                null, // view: should be window
                true, // ctrlKey
                false, // altKey
                true, // shiftKey
                false, // metaKey
                0, // keyCode: unsigned long - the virtual key code, else 0
                "P".charCodeAt(0), // charCode: unsigned long - the Unicode character associated with the depressed key, else 0
            );
            document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
        }

        
        document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
            console.log(event, 'ctrlKey: ' + e.ctrlKey, 'shiftKey: ' + e.shiftKey, e.char, e.key);
            e.preventDefault();

        });

        // trigger
        setTimeout(function () {
            keypressEvt()
        }, 2000)

    </script>
```

Comment: What is a shortcut key event?

Comment: Custom shortcut in Chrome extensions. Just like: Ctrl + Shift + P，show the popup.thml